# Why my command prompt display the wrong script?

Tags: batch-file

So today i've got one problem at work, i made a script (Event.bat) who begin like this :

```
@echo off  
set /p value="How many time do we execute this?"  
[Code is not important here]
```

After that, i created an other script ("Test.bat"), but just with one simple command :

```
@echo off 
[My command] 
echo it's OK
```

The problem is, when i execute the second one (Test.bat), my command prompt always display :
"How many time do we execute this?"

But it's clearly not the display off the good one.

Do you already have this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to exit the first script.

To exit the script and not the `cmd.exe` you need to issue `EXIT /B` command at the end of the first (then the second script).

Comment: Easy, I'm almost ashamed of not having thought about it earlier ... Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Mickael you are welcome - please don't forget to https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers